# Powershell Mongodb Authentication

Tags: mongodb, powershell, database-connection, driver

can anyone tell me how to connect mongodb with authentication using power shell? I see references with local host connection but don't see mongodb server connection string.

Any references are welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet of MongoDb authentication from Powershell.

I use here MongoDB C# driver (have a look [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/))

```
# Mongo DB driver
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Path_To_mongocsharpdriver\mongocsharpdriver.1.9.2\lib\net35\MongoDB.Bson.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Path_To_mongocsharpdriver\mongocsharpdriver.1.9.2\lib\net35\MongoDB.Driver.dll'

# Connexion to MongoDB
$connectionString = "mongodb://user1:password1@localhost"
$db =  "MyDBName"
$collection =  "MyCollectionName"

function Get-MongoDBCollection ($connectionString, $db, $collection)
{
  $mongoClient = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient($connectionString)
  $mongoServer = $mongoClient.GetServer()
  $mongoDatabase = $mongoServer.GetDatabase($db)
  $mongoCollection = $mongoDatabase.GetCollection($collection)
  return $mongoCollection
}

$FileName = $args[0]
# get the file name 
$FileNameLeaf = Split-Path $FileName -Leaf

# Connect to MongoDB and get collection
$mongoCollection = Get-MongoDBCollection $connectionString $db $collection

# Verify if this file is integrated
$query = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument('Fic_Data', $FileNameLeaf)
$found = $mongoCollection.FindOne($query)
if ($found -ne $null)
{
  Write-Host "`tThe file $FileNameLeaf is integrated !"
  return
}
```

Comment: I assume this does not work with the latest MongoDB driver, since I had the same issue with almost the same script about get-collection. Can you provide a solution for the latest driver? Since it would actually solve my bounty too.

Comment: This was my question which is similar to this but I need it for the latest C# driver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878209/powershell-not-compatible-with-mongodb-c-sharp-drivers-methods

Comment: I also have it with the latest driver, but I haven't got the snippet with me now.

Comment: Would be great if you post it later