# PowerShell not compatible with MongoDB C# Driver's Methods?

Tags: c#, mongodb, powershell, generics

Problem with latest MongoDB Driver caused by the C# Generics:

```
Cannot find an overload for "GetCollection" and the argument count: "1".
```

I could probably use other GetCollection methods without the generics, but I do not know how exactly.

The answer posted further down points out some good information but unfortunately the provided code was the same than I already tried and it is not working.

Here is what I would like to do:

I want to work with PowerShell to create a few documents.
The issue I am facing now seems that "GetCollection" does not work properly. I think it has to do with the lack of support for generics in Powershell. Anyway I found some CmdLets to run generic methods. But I think this will make the code too complicated. Is there a way to get around this issue?

I saw that there are other GetCollection methods which are not based on C# Generics, but I do not understand yet how to use them in PowerShell.

Powershell Exception: `Cannot find an overload for "GetCollection" and the argument count: "1"`

```
# Mongo DB driver
Add-Type -Path 'CSharpDriver-2.0.1\MongoDB.Bson.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'CSharpDriver-2.0.1\MongoDB.Driver.dll'

# Conncetion to MongoDB
$connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27018"
$db =  "TestDB"
$collection =  "Test"


function Get-MongoDBCollection ($connectionString, $db, $collection)
{
   $mongoClient = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient($connectionString)
   $mongoDatabase = $mongoClient.GetDatabase($db)
   $mongoCollection = $mongoDatabase.GetCollection($collection)
   return $mongoCollection
}


# Connect to MongoDB and get collection
$mongoCollection = Get-MongoDBCollection $connectionString $db $collection
```

The code listed above is copied (and slightly changed) from an earlier SO question: [Powershell Mongodb Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695670/powershell-mongodb-authentication)

Any suggestion how this can be done? I assume that the code listed in the SO is based on an earlier driver version. I think that is why it is not working any more.

Full Exeption on PowerShell console:

```
Cannot find an overload for "GetCollection" and the argument count: "1".
At F:\PowerShell\CreateDB.ps1:31 char:3
+   $mongoCollection = $mongoDatabase.GetCollection($collection)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help with this? The question is still open and I think there are a lot of PowerShell experts out there.

Answer (score 10):

I hope this can still be of some help, this worked for me with the latest C# Driver and the current MongoDB RC-4.

```
function Get-MongoDBCollection {
Param(
    $database,
    $CollectionName,
    $settings = $null, #[MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionSetting]
    $returnType = [PSOBJECT]
)
    $method = $database.GetType().GetMethod('GetCollection')
    $gericMethod = $method.MakeGenericMethod($returnType)
    $gericMethod.Invoke($database,[object[]]($CollectionName,$settings))
}
$Collection = Get-MongoDBCollection $database 'test'
# or 
$Collection = Get-MongoDBCollection $database 'test' -returnType  ([MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument])
```

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post more code. How does the Get-DB Method look like? I tried your code but still have errors. So how do you use the $database variable. It is obviously not just the name of the database.

Comment: Maybe you did not see my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered proxying the call to mongo through some custom .Net code and then loading that .Net assembly into Powershell?  You could have overloads in your c# code to deal with the varying types.

You can use the steps [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell/) to load the custom assembly.

Then in your custom method(s) you could convert the generic types into types that Powershell can understand.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. Thought that must be easier. But probably it is not.

Answer (score -1):

I think you've already answered this question with some of the statements in your question:

> I think it has to do with the lack of support for generics in Powershell

and

> the code listed in the SO is based on an earlier driver version. I think that is why it is not working any more

[This link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver?jmp=docs&_ga=1.92855444.805444570.1438953788#comment-2058269012) confirms what you've said above and also contains some feedback on v2 of the driver.

See below for an excerpt from [the main page](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver), there is a suggestion that the old driver is still available:

> you may prefer to use the 1.10 version of the driver

So maybe it would be best for you to locate the older version and continue with that.

**EDIT:**

In case it is a problem with the newer API, it looks like there is still support for the old version. From the above link, perhaps you should try:

```
function Get-MongoDBCollection ($connectionString, $db, $collection)
{
  $mongoClient = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient($connectionString)
  $mongoServer = $mongoClient.GetServer()
  $mongoDatabase = $mongoServer.GetDatabase($db)
  $mongoCollection = $mongoDatabase.GetCollection($collection)
  return $mongoCollection
}
```

Comment: This is not possible since I want to work with WiredTiger and programs working with the old driver versions are not compatible to the latest mongo server with wired tiger enabled. I saw in the C Sharp mongoDB driver documentation that there are alternative method signatures for getcollection. I just do not understand yet how to use them.

Comment: I even saw modules for calling generic methods from powershell which could solve the issue possibly. But the syntax then looks not natural anymore. So I would like to work with the other methods which do not rely on generics. I think they are still inside the driver.

Comment: See here: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_GetCollection.htm

Comment: See the edit, if that doesn't work I'm all out of ideas I'm afraid. Following the path in the docs you linked to, `MongoServer.GetDatabase` seems to return a `MongoDatabase` rather than an `IMongoDatabase` which the `MongoClient` returns. `MongoDatabase` contains the overloaded `GetCollection` without the generics

Comment: I meant that is exactly what I was trying :)

Comment: Did you test what you wrote here? I mean I appreciate your contribution, but the issue is really how to use the get collection without generic.

Comment: So my last comment / edit tries to address that. You didn't update the question to show that you already tried this so I have no way of knowing that, do I. And no, I didn't test it because I don't have a MongoDB install handy. Simply trying to help. Rest-assured I appreciate the downvote for taking time out to do that.

Comment: Please excuse me I did not say it in my question. Unfortunately the approach is not working, so although I appreciate that you are trying to help giving you an upvote would be misleading for other visitors.

Comment: Well that is your decision. The hover over for the downvote button comment states "This answer is not useful". I would dispute that this is not useful, it may not have worked, but it's a detailed answer nonetheless and you've downvoted knowing that it was written without my knowledge that you'd already tried this method. Simply leaving it without up/downvoting at all and adding a comment saying it doesn't work would've been perfectly sufficient here